# POST terminal output to cURL

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to post the output of uptime to cURL post on a HTTPS address
The problem is that I must send the output preceded by "message=" in the -d option. Each time I run the below command I get : **-bash: @-: command not found**

```
echo "time=`uptime`" | curl -X POST "https://url/hook/abcd123" -d "message=`@-`"
```

Any idea on how to include cURL @- with the mandatory message= field of the URL I am sending the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backticks in

```
`@-`
```

have a special meaning for Bash. They are a command substitution, meaning Bash will try to execute `@-` and insert that output into the command line. Naturally, that doesn't work, as `@-` isn't a valid bash command. Also, the way of combining STDIN and your text wouldn't work either anyway. Try

```
time=`uptime` && curl -X POST "https://url/hook/abcd123" -d "message=$time"
```

Comment: Hello Sven, thanks for the explanation - worked like a charm. -Marc